# How do I prevent wake up from suspend by internal laptop keyboard

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, suspend, power-management, wakeup

My laptop always wakes up from suspend when I take it in my bag, even the lid is closed, because keys of the keyboard are clicked.

I need that only the power button will wake up the laptop from suspend.

this is my /proc/acpi/wakeup :

```
    Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEGP      S3    *disabled
PEG1      S3    *disabled
PEGP      S3    *disabled
PEG2      S3    *disabled
PEGP      S3    *disabled
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
RP06      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP07      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP09      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0
RP10      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S3    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
```